# What is the syntax for input parameters (variables) in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to pass parameter to my Query using MySQL as you can see in the code below. but it gives me No Records always .... any advise why?>

```
create table DemoTable
(
   Id int,
   FirstName varchar(20),
   LastName varchar(20)
);
insert into DemoTable values(10,'Carol','Taylor');
select * from DemoTable;
set @myId:=10;
select *from DemoTable where Id=@myId;
```

---

0 ROWS SELECTED

Comment: Seems to to me its working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=effdcef855205966ac0ada1023465b0c Keep in mind variables are only for current session...

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eSphnyg5dyBwzrsNr8ggtx/0 Also working when declared in right session.

Comment: thank you so much guys for help it's working fine with me as well and I found the issue which I was using execute the statement under the keyboard cursor instead of executing the selected portion under MySQL...